# Taken photo is bigger than the preview in cameraview

Tags: android, camera, camera-view

I'm facing a problem using a Samsung J1 device here.
But the image taken is bigger than the preview one.

This is the preview that I got:
[image]

and this is the final bitmap result:

[image]

I'm calling camera view with this attributes:

```
<com.otaliastudios.cameraview.CameraView
android:id="@+id/camera"
app:cameraGesturePinch="zoom"
app:cameraFlash="auto"
app:cameraAutoFocusResetDelay="0"
app:cameraGestureTap="focusWithMarker"
android:keepScreenOn="true"
app:cameraPreview="glSurface"
app:cameraPictureSizeSmallest="true"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
app:cameraGestureScrollHorizontal="exposureCorrection"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

I already tried to use cameraPictureSizeAspectRatio with 4:3 but no success with it.

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: You would need to ask the developers of that library. It looks to me like the preview and the photo match, if you ignore the green brackets. Is that library documented to crop to the area marked by the brackets?

Comment: nah, the brackets now is just useless. Didnt match because of, look at the preview where the GitHub logo is, at the bottom. And look at the bitmap itself

Comment: In the preview, the lower right corner shows the first 3.5 letters of "About", under the overlay. In the photo, the lower right corner shows the first 3.5 letters of "About".

Comment: Yep, the problem is the height of the image

Comment: And I dont know it is AspectRatio problem or not

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem .
after save image from cameraview ( i use camerakit lib) , display file by convert it to bitmap in imageview .

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    cameraKitView = findViewById(R.id.camera)

    val captureButton = findViewById<View>(R.id.button_capture) as Button
    val imageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.myImageView)

    captureButton.setOnClickListener {
        cameraKitView!!.captureImage { _, capturedImage ->
            val savedPhoto = getOutputMediaFile()
            try {
                val outputStream = FileOutputStream(savedPhoto!!.path)
                outputStream.write(capturedImage)
                outputStream.close()
                val myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(savedPhoto.getAbsolutePath())
                imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap)
            } catch (e: java.io.IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my layout :

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.camerakit.CameraKitView
    android:id="@+id/camera"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_capture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="@string/save"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:alpha="0.5"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

but when show image and want to take another image, cameraview is not as scale as imageview

**Solved :**
just change scaleType to CentreCrop . that is it